# Which de Rham representations are trianguline?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $K/\mathbf{Q}_p$ be a finite extension, and let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $\overline{\mathbf{Q}_p}$-vector space with a continuous action of $G_K$.  Suppose $V$ is de Rham, so potentially semistable.  Let $L/K$ be an extension over which $V$ becomes semistable, with maximal absolutely unramified subfield $L_0$.  Choose an embedding $\tau:L_0 \to \overline{\mathbf{Q}_p}$ and set $W=(V \otimes_{L_0,\tau}\mathbf{B}_{\mathrm{st}})^{\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/L)}$. A standard construction of Fontaine produces from $W$ a Weil-Deligne representation $\mathrm{WD}(V)=(W,\rho,N)$ independent of all choices. Let $\pi=\mathrm{rec}_K^{-1}(\mathrm{WD}(V))$ be its local Langlands correspondent.  Here is a natural speculation:

> The following conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $V$ is trianguline.
> 2. $(W,\rho)^{ss}$ is totally reducible.
> 3. $\pi$ is a subquotient of a representation induced from the Borel subgroup of
>      $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$.

Is this considered anywhere in the literature?  When $n=2$ this is a theorem of Nakamura, but things simplify a bit since in that case the third condition above is the same as "$\pi$ is not supercuspidal".

Comment: The formulation is imprecise about the coefficient field ($n$-dimensional over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ or $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p$ or...) and "totally reducible" should be defined (giving due attention to the coefficient field).

Comment: Due attention given.

Comment: Nice question. I presume you know Berger-Chenevier's paper and that you have checked its result are compatible with your conjecture?

Comment: David, so you have a precise reference for the case $n=2$?

Comment: Hi Joel, it's Theorem A.4 in this paper of Nakamura: http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1230

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the equivalence of 2. and 3. is a fairly easy consequence of Bernstein-Zelevinsky.